# KNP Pagination in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, paginator, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

I am using symfony2.6 with knp paginator bundle. On simple page It's working perfect. But When I implement pagination on page which one load by ajax call then it's not working.

So for this I implement something different with ajax call. In click on next page I sent ajax call and the rest remaining product id. That product id I am sending through ajax and get the data via query and then set again in pagination then render but Data is coming and pagination is not working.

My code is here :-

```
        <div class="pagination">
   //entities -> all products
        {{ knp_pagination_render(entities) }}
        <script>
            var attr = product.id;
            $(document).on("click",".s_p_c_pagination .pagination a",function(evt){
                $('#mainCntData').css("opacity", "0.3");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $(this).attr('href'),
                    data:{ "attarFil" : attr },
                })
                .done(function( data ) {
                       //Result Div
                });
                evt.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
```

Controller :-

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $keyword = $request->get('data');
            if(!empty($keyword)){
                        $result = $query->getResult($keyword);
                        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
                        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
                                $result,
                                $this->get('request')->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
                                10/*limit per page*/
                        );
                        return $this->render('ABCBundle:Home:index.html.twig', array('entities' => $pagination));
            }else{

                if($request->isMethod('POST')){
                    $productId = $request->get('attarFil');
                    $pageNo = $request->get('page');
                    $product = $em->getRepository('HousePlansAppBundle:Product')->findBy(array('id'=>$productId));
                    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
                    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
                            $generateId,
                            $this->get('request')->query->getInt('page', $pageNo)/*page number*/,
                            10/*limit per page*/
                    );
                    return $this->render('ABCBundle:Home:index.html.twig', array('entities' => $pagination));
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Quick tip: Instead of using `$this->get('request')` ... just add `..Action(Request $request)`, Symfony will inject the Request object into your controller automatically or .. inject the RequestStack via DI and call `getCurrentRequest`.That's cleaner and easier to test. You don;t need to manually get the `page` parameter from the request, too.  The bundle has this functionality builtin - see the [configuration options](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle#configuration-example).

Comment: Regarding your question: Provide more information, please! **Data is coming and pagination is not working** doesn't describe your problem well enough for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: @nifr Thanks for support. This one "Action(Request $request)"
 I already added  in my controller. Data is coming means I get remaining data through product id via doctrine query.

Comment: @nifr Please check updated controller.

Comment: This is incomplete or not working at all `$result = $query->getResult($keyword);` ... `$query` was never set.

Comment: @nifr this just a sample , real one is this :- $result= $em->getRepository('ABCBundle:Product')->findBy(array('status'=>'1'));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152756/discussion-between-kunwar-siddharth-singh-and-nifr).